# Flexbox changes size after reload

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create simple page header with a logo on the left-hand side and links divided evenly on the right-hand side. Like this [render from Adobe Xd presenting expected header design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifLiO.png). To do this I have written this code (snippet is missing the image and is a bit too narrow for this margin):

```css
header {
  margin: 0 200px;
  height: 75px;
  border-bottom: #707070 solid 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header .logo {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

header nav {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header nav a {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="home.html">
      <img alt="Logo Hufca" src="logo_hufca_zlote.svg" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="active.html">Działalność</a>
    <a href="unit.html">Jednostki</a>
    <a href="docs.html">Dokumenty</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

This solution works as expected in certain cases on Chrome and Opera. The layout is correct after the first load of page [(screenshot from Chrome after the first page load)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs3hK.png). It also scales adequately to viewport resizing. Then, after clicking some links, `<nav>` become narrower and `flex` is not flexible anymore - doesn't change size when viewport does [(screenshot from Chrome after the bug occures)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxGr6.png). 
On Firefox and Edge this solution doesn't work at all - bug occurs all the time.
[You can test this page here.](https://wip.733mdh.pl/pl/dzialalnosc) Even more confusing is fact that the footer (made with flexbox) works propoerly on the same page. How can I repair my code to make header looks as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with a static `margin`. Its better to use a relative CSS rule to achieve the space between content and borders. Also you dont need to set `flex-grow` & `flex-basis`.

But the main issue was that the `img { height: 100% }` caused that the `img` element rise to its full height. You have to give the `header .logo` a `max-height` attribute.
Also its better to achieve the space between the nav elements with padding.

Here is a possible solution:

```css
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 75px;
  border-bottom: #707070 solid 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header .logo {
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 65px;
}

img {
   height: 100%;
}

header nav {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header nav a {
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

header nav a:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="home.html">
      <img alt="Logo Hufca" src="https://wip.733mdh.pl/user/themes/motyw-hufca/images/logo_hufca_zlote.svg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="active.html">Działalność</a>
    <a href="unit.html">Jednostki</a>
    <a href="docs.html">Dokumenty</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  height: 75px;
  border-bottom: #707070 solid 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header .logo {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: auto;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

header nav {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header nav a {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="home.html">
      <img alt="Logo Hufca" src="https://picsum.photos/200/50" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="active.html">Działalność</a>
    <a href="unit.html">Jednostki</a>
    <a href="docs.html">Dokumenty</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```